# Why does $\frac{\sum X_i^2}{n} \rightarrow \sigma^2+\mu^2$?

Tags: convergence

I cannot find a reference to the proof of this, but I found

$$\frac{\sum X_i^2}{n} \rightarrow \sigma^2+\mu^2$$

From: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1416911/248602

So why does it converge to that?

Comment: @Glen_b http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1416911/248602

Comment: Oh, that's the "source", right? Please edit the link into your question. The proof is right there ("by [strong law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law) (SLLN)"), applied exactly as I suggested above. I can write it as an answer if you like.

Comment: The question is missing definitions of $X_i$, $\sigma^2$ and $\mu$.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala The usual statistical meanings. $X_i$ is a random variable, $\sigma^2=Var(X_i)$ and $\mu$ is a mean.

Answer (score 4):

I presume you're already happy to [accept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law) that -- in the limit as $n\to\infty$ -- $\bar{Y} \to E(Y)$ (as long as $E(Y)$ is finite.

Now let $Y_i=X_i^2$. Then clearly also (in the limit) $\overline{X^2}\to E(X^2)$ (again, as long as the expectation of $Y$ is finite).

But $\text{Var}(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$ so $E(X^2) =  \sigma_X^2 + \mu_X^2$.

Hence by the strong law of large numbers, $\lim_{n\to\infty}
\overline{X^2}\to \sigma_X^2 + \mu_X^2$.

Comment: Could you clarify, why $Var(X) \rightarrow \sigma^2$?

Comment: Also what's the meaning of $\bar{Y} \rightarrow E(Y)$? I mean how to interpret it to "be the same" as $\bar{X} \rightarrow \mu$?

Comment: Strictly speaking it's shorthand but read it as "As $n\to\infty$ sample means  converge to their expectation". *Obviously* it doesn't matter whether the variable is called $X$ or $Y$.

Comment: @mavavilj Var(X) doesn't converge to $\sigma^2$, it *is* $\sigma^2$.